# Python select data for top 3 values per group in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

From the given dataframe sorted by ID and Date:

```
ID  Date        Value
1   12/10/1998  0
1   04/21/2002  21030
1   08/16/2013  56792
1   09/18/2014  56792
1   09/14/2016  66354
2   06/16/2015  46645
2   12/08/2015  47641
2   12/11/2015  47641
2   04/13/2017  47641
3   07/29/2009  28616
3   03/31/2011  42127
3   03/17/2013  56000
```

I would like to get values for top 3 Dates, group by ID:

```
56792
56792
66354
47641
47641
47641
28616
42127
56000
```

I need values only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) both by `ID` and `Date`, and use [`GroupBy.tail`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to take the values for the top 3 dates:

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df.sort_values(['ID','Date']).groupby('ID').Value.tail(3).to_numpy()

# array([56792, 56792, 66354, 47641, 47641, 47641, 28616, 42127, 56000])
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you